# Visual Studio Code não marca funções

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Em JS meu Visual Studio não está colocando o parênteses automaticamente após as funções...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por ex, no meu VS aparece as opções com os nomes das funções q eu posso escolher normalmente (como na img acima), porem se eu escolho uma opção, a random, por ex, ele apenas escreve random no código, e não random(), com os parentes indicando q é uma função...

Parece um detalhe bobo, mas p/ quem tá aprendendo gera mta confusão, já q há alguns métodos/funções q não precisa colocar mesmo o () como o lenght por ex.... assim eu nunca sei qd uso o () ou não... :(

Sei q o VS coloca automaticamente pq já assisti videos usando o VS em q o () é colocado automatico qd clica no nome da função nas opções, mas no meu VS isso não acontece... alguem sabe como eu arrumo isso?

Comment: Todo método precisa de (), Length é só um atributo, e não uma função

Comment: vc está em um arquivo .JS?

Comment: Este é o comportamento normal do vs code.

Comment: Você já tem emmet? link: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet

Comment: instala prettier ele formata o codigo automaticamente quando salva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só marcar a propriedade `javascript.suggest.completeFunctionCalls` nas suas settings.

(Clique em executar pra ver o gif exemplo)

```html
<div style='position:relative; padding-bottom:calc(40.34% + 44px)'><iframe src='https://gfycat.com/ifr/CleverActualHornbill' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='100%' height='100%' style='position:absolute;top:0;left:0;' allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
```

*Resposta traduzida de https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126232/12913985*